# Mostrar datos desde controlador a jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

buen día.

Quería saber si se puede mandar datos desde un controlador en c# a una function con Jquery.

Es que cuando agrego una nueva "atención", que serían como comentarios, que se agregue también quien hizo ese comentario.

```
var correo = (User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity).Name;
var agente = db.Agentes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Correo == correo);
ViewBag.Agente = agente.Nombre;
```

Tengo estas 2 variables, donde en la variable de correo obtengo el correo del que inicio sesión y en la de agente, obtengo por medio de la variable correo, el correo del usuario quien inicio sesión. Y ya en el viewbag paso la variable agente donde apunto al nombre del usuario que ingreso.

Y para mandar esa info, tengo una function donde por medio de AJAX envió y muestro esa info.

```
function Atenciones() {

        console.log('atenciones');
        showSpinner();

        var URL = '@Url.Action("AtencionesPorSolicitudId", "SolicitudAtenciones")' + '/' + '@ViewBag.SolicitudId';
        console.log('url ' + URL);
        var card = "";
        $.getJSON({
            url: URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //var d = (JSON.parse(data));
                console.log(data);

                $.each(data.atenciones, function (i, o) {

                    card += "<div class='row'>";
                    card += "<div class='col-md-6'>";
                    card += "<div class='card card-default'>";

                    //CARD HEADER
                    card += "<div class='card-header with-border'>";
                    //card += "<h3 class='card-title'>Atención</h3><div class='float-right'>Fecha: " + dateToDMY(new Date(o.Fecha.substr(o.Fecha.indexOf("(") + 1, 13) - 0)) + "</div><br/>";
                    card += "<h3 class='card-title'>Atención</h3><div class='float-right' >Fecha: <span >" + $.format.toBrowserTimeZone(new Date(o.Fecha.substr(o.Fecha.indexOf("(") + 1, 13) - 0)) + "</span></div><br/>";
                    card += "</div>";

                    card += "<div class='card-body'>";

                    //AGENTE
                    card += "<div><label>Agente</label></div><br/>" + '@ViewBag.Agente';
```

(No lo muestro todo por que es mucho) Pero aquí donde tengo marcado como comentario, le agrego un div y un label, y el ViewBag apuntando al agente.

Algo así me quedaría al final.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar @Html.Raw para imprimir un texto en el documento, ya sea en la parte html, javascript o css

```
let agente = '@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Agente)';
```

Por otro lado y fuera del ámbito de tu pregunta, te recomiendo averiguar sobre vistas parciales y la función load de jquery. Con la primera creas una vista que es una pequeña porción de código, por ejemplo una ventana modal (pero solo el código de la ventana) y con load cargas esa ventana por ajax. De esta manera, tu función "Atenciones" serían solo un par de líneas de código

Answer (score 0):

Tan solo abrí las herramientas de desarrollador apretando la tecla F12. Y desglose un objeto que tenía con todas las "Atenciones" que tenia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y busque la variable que quería obtener y lo cambie por el que tenía en la función del AJAX.

```
//AGENTE
card += "<div><label>Agente</label><br>" + o.Usuario + "</div><br>";
```

Y que el parámetro de la función, apunta al objeto.